# Host the WebJobs SDK .NetCore in a WindowsService. How to start the services when both have to call Host.Run

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

How to use v3.x of the WebJobs SDK in a .NET Core WindowsService that extends
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService, that also needs to call `Host.Run`?

There is a github [issue requesting an example solution](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/116498).

Some code about 'How to use the Azure WebJobs SDK for event-driven background processing', exist in the [documentation for v3 WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#version-3x-8)

Answer (score 0):

To run the Azure WebJobs background service Host to subscribe to Azure Storage events, e.g. QueueTrigger, and to host that service witin a Windows Service as a BackgroundService (The new .net core way of Windows Services):

```
  const string ServiceName = "InsolDataSync";
  private const string AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGEQUEUEBATCHSIZE = "AzureWebJobsStorageQueueBatchSize";
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
#if DEBUG                
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
#endif
    .Add(new EncryptedConfigurationSource(applicationNameWithoutExtension))
    .Build();

  var _batchsize = configuration[AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGEQUEUEBATCHSIZE];
  var batchsize = 1;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_batchsize) && Int32.TryParse(_batchsize, out batchsize))
    if (batchsize > 5) batchsize = 5; //upper limit is 5;

  IHostBuilder functionsBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
      b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
      b.AddAzureStorageBlobs(bloboptions => {
        bloboptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
    });
    b.AddAzureStorageQueues(options =>
    {
      options.BatchSize = batchsize;
    });
  })
  .ConfigureServices(svcs =>
    {
      svcs.AddSingleton(configuration);
      svcs.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(new QueueNameResolver());//allows for custom naming of QueueTrigger names
      svcs.AddSingleton<JokeService>();
      svcs.AddWindowsService(options =>
      {
        options.ServiceName = ServiceName;
      });
      svcs.AddHostedService<MyWindowsBackgroundService>();
      LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<EventLogSettings, EventLogLoggerProvider>(svcs);
  })
  .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
      options.ServiceName = ServiceName;
    });
    var functionsHost = functionsBuilder.Build();
    //perform pre-startup activities, e.g. on first use run an installer
    functionsHost.Run();
```